# Theorem 9.40 Baby rudin

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

[image]

I don't understand the last equality.

Why is $h[(D_1f)(x,b+k) - (D_1f)(x,b)]$ equal of $hk(D_{21}f)(x,y).$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have$$(D_1f)(x,b+k)-(D_1f)(x,b)=k(D_{21}f)(x,y)$$for some $y\in(b,b+k)$ by the Mean Value Theorem and because $D_1f$ is differentable.

Comment: The expression $D_{21}f$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to the second variable of $D_1f$. And we are assuming that $D_{21}f$ exists, but we are not assuming that $D_{11}f$ exists.